# Im trying to estimate parameters for Weibull Burr X with fixed covariate function

Tags: r, estimation, mle

I tried to run MLE codings for R, but the output is "initial value out of range"

```
library(maxLik)
 
 # -log-likelihood function of the Weibull Burr X + fixed covariate distribution.
 likelihood<-function(par){
   
   x<-data2$x; yi<-data2$yi; 
   
   alpha<-par[1];beta<-par[2];theta<-par[3];tau0<-par[4];tau1<-par[5];
   n<-nrow(data2)
   a<-sum(((exp(tau0+tau1*yi))*x)^2)
   b<-sum(log(x))
   c<-sum(log(1-exp(-((exp(tau0+tau1*yi))*x)^2))^theta)
   d<-sum(log(1-(1-exp(-(exp(tau0+tau1*yi))*x)^2)^theta))
   e<-sum((((1-exp(-((exp(tau0+tau1*yi))*x)^2))^(theta*beta))/
             ((1-(1-exp(-((exp(-(tau0+tau1*yi)))*x)^2))^theta))^beta))
   
   #n = 30
   logL<-n*log(2*alpha*beta*((exp(tau0+tau1*yi))^2)*theta)- a +
      b + (theta*beta-1)*c
     -(beta-1)*d
     -alpha*log(e)
   
   
   return(logL)
  
   }
 
max<-maxLik(likelihood,start=c(1.1,4.15,0.25,0.03,0.02))
summary(max)
```

How to fix this to estimate the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend calculating the log likelihood analytically first, where you pay attention to simplify it as much as possible, before putting it into your R function. This usually avoids running into numerical issues. For instance, taking the simple log(exp(x)) on the computer can lead to numerical issues for very large x, but log(exp(x))=x will not.

Secondly, have you tried plugging in your starting values in your function to see if a reasonable value is returned?